# How to use model-form in flatpages django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-flatpages

I stuck in code where i want to use model-form in flatpage template.
I create model-form and that form need to serve in flatpage template with save functionality.

Answer (score 0):

(I know this is old, but just in case other are looking at it)

I don't think you can as flat-pages are associated 'simple “flat” HTML content'. This include stuff like 'About-us' pages or private policies.

Usually you want to maintain Forms data within Views which you can access their data from it. This allows you to use the data to send emails or process logins.